# Bash variable substitution in a function

Tags: regex, bash

I have a function read_command defined as:

```
function read_command {
    local __newline __lines __input __newstr __tmp i;
    exec 3< "$*";
    __newline=$'\n';
    __lines=();
    while IFS= read <&3 -r __line && [ "$__line" != '####' ]; do
        echo "$__line";
        __lines+=("$__line");
    done
    while IFS= read <&3 -r __line && [ "$__line" != '####' ]; do
        read -e -p "${__line#*:}$PS2" __input;
        local ${__line%%:*}="$__input";
    done
    __command="";
    for i in "${__lines[@]}"; do
        __tmp=$(echo "${i}");
        __command="${__command} ${__newline} ${__tmp}";
    done
    echo -e "$__command";
}
```

In the current directory there is a file named "test", with the following
content:

```
greet ${a:-"Bob"} 
greet ${b:-"Jim"}
####
a: name of friend a
b: name of friend b
####
```

In the terminal, the command executed is

```
read_command test
```

With no input, I am expecting the output of the last statement to be:

```
greet Bob
greet Jim
```

But what I get is:

```
greet ${a:-"Bob"}  
greet ${b:-"Jim"}
```

What is wrong here?

Edit: As suggested by David, adding eval works in some cases except the following one.

```
j=1;i="export DISPLAY=:0 && Xephyr :${j}&";k=$(eval echo "$i");
echo $k
```

> > export DISPLAY=:0

I am expecting k to be "export DISPLAY=:0 && Xephyr :1&", what's wrong here?
Edit: I tried with the following

```
k=$(eval "echo \"$i\"")
```

This is the link to the script I am working on.
https://gist.github.com/QiangF/565102ba3b6123942b9bf6b897c05f87

Comment: The semicolons at end of line are superfluous; in shell script, a new line *or* a semicolon is sufficient as a command separator.

Comment: I am just following an example, there are too many bad examples on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the first `while` loop, in `echo "$__line"`, you have `__line='greet ${a:-"Bob"}'`. When you try to print that, Bash won't be expanding `${a:-"Bob"}` into `Bob`. (Even if you remove the quotes around `$__line` this won't happen.) To get that effect, you need to add `eval`, as in, e.g., `eval echo "$__line"`. Unfortunately `eval` comes with its can of worms, you have to start worrying about interactions between quoting levels and such.

Comment: How to prevent "eval echo $__line"  from executing the command in __line, please see the edit in the question.

Comment: This is looking very much like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you actually trying to solve with this code?  This is also looking vaguely like http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: The alternative for the cheat.sh is to use template substitution, but it is less convinient. (https://github.com/tests-always-included/mo)

Comment: `eval` consumes the primary quoting level, meaning that: `eval $v` and `eval "$v"` do the same thing, for all contents of `$v`. To manipulate what `bash` does after expanding `eval`'s arguments, you need to use second-level quotes, meaning quotes that won't be consumed at the first level. So, try `eval echo \"$line\"`. Things quickly get nasty if `$line` also contains quotes, but it looks like it doesn't in your case, so it should be ok.